# User-implemented accessors

Tags: c#, accessor

My code is currently infinity looping and I am not sure why.  I am trying to implement a get,set accessor that checks that the accepted number is between 0-100 and if not it will set the value equal to zero.  Can't quite put my finger on what I am doing wrong any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public double Quiz1
{
    get { return Quiz1; }
    set 
    {
        if (value > 0 && value < 101)
        {
            Quiz1 = value;
        }
        else
        {
            Quiz1 = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `return Quiz1` inside of the `get`ter, you're recursively calling the `get`ter over and over again.

[Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) (e.g. `public double Quiz1 { get; set; }`) provide a hidden field in which the property's value is *actually* stored.

When implementing [traditional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k69wcs43.aspx) (non-auto) `get` and `set` methods for a property, there is no auto-generated backing field.

Thus, you typically need to add a backing variable as well:

```
private double m_quiz1;

public double Quiz1
{
    get { return m_quiz1; }
    set 
    {
        if (value > 0 && value < 101)
        {
            m_quiz1= value;
        }
        else
        {
            m_quiz1= 0;
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) - MSDN